# How to unescape double quotes in Symfony using JMS Serializer

Tags: json, symfony, serialization, escaping, jmsserializerbundle

I'm using JMS Serializer (jms/serializer-bundle) in Symfony 3.4 to serialize an object to JSON.

The object contains a property called **text** which is a string value containing double quotes. JMS Serializer escapes all the double quotes with a backslash on serialization. So the field looks like this on output:

```
"text": "<p>\"My concern is the President. It's not okay, it's horrible,\" he said.</p>"
```

This is okay for normal strings, but if the string contains json itself, it becomes invalid json

```
"text": "[[{\"fid\":\"123456\",\"view_mode\":\"content\",\"attributes\":{\"height\":\"400\",\"width\":\"800\"}}]]"
```

How can I get it to not escape double quotes on JSON Serialization?

Answer (score 0):

The value of the "text" property is still a string, or a string of serialized json. This is why it escapes the quotes.

One solution would be to deserialize the json string, so that the value of "text" is a nested object, before you serialize the whole object.

Alternatively you could try [stripcslashes](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stripcslashes.php) on the string after deserialization.